# PowerShell - storing multiple query results in a single variable

Tags: sql-server, powershell

**TL;DR:** I'm looking for a way to append SQL query results to a PowerShell DataRow variable to continue storing results from multiple queries.

I'm fairly new to PowerShell, and I have 'inherited' a script at work which runs an internal (company-developed) PowerShell wrapper script as a front-end to querying an MS SQL database.  Basically the script does this:

$results = .\wrapper-script ""

$results.GetType() tells me it is an object of type System.Data.DataRow.

The contents of $result are processed downstream and all of this works fine.

However the SQL SELECT statement parameters are getting longer and longer (it's querying for attributes of specific servers out of an asset database) as the list of hosts I need to pull data for gets longer.  So I was trying to modify the script so that I could just populate a text file with the hosts to query for, reading that in with Get-Content and then using a 'foreach' loop to iterate thru that host list and run a single SQL query per host, sleep a bit (to not hammer the db), and just keep appending each result set to that $results variable.  I tried the following:

```
$serverList = Get-Content -Path /path/to/file
foreach ($item in $serverList) {
    $curObj = .\wrapper-script "<sql SELECT statement>"
    $results += $curObj
}
```

But the script bombs out here and I'm not sure yet of the reason, but I'm guessing that += is not a valid operation on this object type and hopefully there's some other way to do it.

I need to keep the object types intact because this is just part of a much larger script, and at my current PoSh skill level I need to operate within these bounds and not bite off more than I can chew.

So ultimately, I'm looking for a way to just keep appending SQL query results into the existing DataRow variable.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem. If you're running multiple SQL files, then they could easily provide  result sets with different definitions; and you can't combine result sets with different definitions.

Comment: If I am following you correctly, then no, the structure (fields/columns) of the result sets will always be the same; the only thing that will change is the values.

Comment: Does it also fail if you try `$results = foreach ($item in $serverList) { .\wrapper-script "<sql SELECT statement>" }` ?

Comment: @Theo, I think that's done it!  It will be a few days to a week before I can try it "for real" but I believe this is the fix.  Will mark as answer, and if anything doesn't work out I'll follow up back here.  Thank you!

Comment: I haven't posted as answer yet, because I believe you need to also send `$item` to the wrapper-script so it knows what hosts to to query for and I will wait for you to test it out. Would like to hear if this helped or not. ;)

Comment: @Theo -- yes, you are spot-on -- $item is already being sent as a parameter to the SELECT. :) I was perhaps oversimplifying the extraneous bits in the original post, but that's already in there.  As far as this working or not goes -- I can at least say that any kind of small-scale testing I can throw at it, looks good so far; but I still can't test full functionality (i.e., making sure everything downstream also works once new entries get populated into this variable) for at least a few days but I'll definitely be back with the result.  Thx again.

Comment: @Theo -- the issue is definitely resolved, it's working fine now with the syntax you suggested.  Thanks again -- will mark as Answer once able to.  Very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jim I'm glad to hear this fixed it. (was away for a few days, so sorry for the late reply). I have posted it as answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my comment as answer.

By adding stuff in a loop to what is to become an array using `+=` concatenation, the entire array needs to be recreated each time, at great cost for memory consumption and processing speed.

It is far more efficient to let Powerhell collect the objects to store with this syntax:

```
$results = foreach ($item in $serverList) { .\wrapper-script "<sql SELECT statement>" }
```